# Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported: ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, payment-gateway, payum

Creating a model for Sofort integration and extend the payments object from the payum module to use it in the capture.

```
<?php

   namespace Reisesparer\Model;

   use Payum\Core\Model\Payment;

   class SofortueberWeisung extends Payment
      {
       protected $id;

       }
```

Controller method for the sofort is like follows: I have created a seperate Model where extend to the payments object

```
public function sofortAction()
{
    $storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum')->getStorage('Reisesparer\Model\SofortueberWeisung');

    $payment = $storage->create();

    $payment->setNumber(uniqid());
    $payment->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
    $payment->setTotalAmount(123); // 1.23 EUR
    $payment->setDescription('A description');
    $payment->setClientId('anId');
    $payment->setClientEmail('foo@example.com');

    $storage->update($payment);

    $captureToken = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
        'sofort', $payment, 'payment_done'
    );
    // print_r($captureToken);
    // exit();

    $this->redirect()->toUrl($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
}
```

And My config file has follows code to configure the payum/sofort mehthod in my project.

```
'sofort' => $sofortFactory->create(array(
            'factory' => 'sofort',
             'config_key' => '12345:123456:edc788a4316ce7e2ac0ede037aa623d7',
         )),
```

And at the last my done action to capture the useful information after the successful payment is like follows:

```
public function doneAction()
{
    $token = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($this);

    $gateway = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum')->getgateway($token->getgatewayName());

    $gateway->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));
    $payment = $status->getFirstModel();
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('status' => $status->getValue(),'details'=>$payment));

    $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/pay_done');

    return $viewModel;
}
```

Storage Config:

```
 'storages' => array(
        $detailsClass => new FilesystemStorage(__DIR__.'/../../data', $detailsClass, 'id'),
        $paymentClass => new FilesystemStorage(__DIR__.'/../../data', $paymentClass, 'id'),
    )
```

Now when ever i proceed with the sofort payment method to capture the payment it gaves me the error and not proceed further. but the other method like paypal, stripe and authorized.net are working fine in the same project how to resolve this issues
 Error:

```
Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported.
```

Comment: @Dymen1 Can you please look over this if it make sense?

Comment: I don't get notifications from mentions ;), but it looks like this action isn't supported for paypal: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/466

Comment: I am using Sofort, Paypal is working fine with the same comfiguration

Comment: @Shoaib what is your storage config?

Comment: I have updated the question with storage  @karser